# Is getting OAuth2 token safe to fetch client-side and pass to server-side?

Tags: oauth2, single-page-app

I'm integrating my application with external service. My application will exchange data with the external service in context of some user. Data exchange will be done in background on server-side.

User must authenticate (**authorization code flow**) in external service and give permission to my application.

On client-side there is SPA (single page application) in Angular.

Server-side is stateless REST API.

Is it safe to do the authentication and grants client-side and then send JWT token to backend?

This is very simple approach and would work like:

1. User clicks "Connect to external app"
2. SPA generates PKCE and redirects to external app's authentication server
3. User authenticates and grants permission to my application
4. User is redirected back to SPA with authorization code
5. SPA gets JWT token from external app's authentication server
6. SPA sends the JWT token (access token and refresh token) to back-end to store it in database

There is another approach that involves server-side and must be stateful:

1. User clicks "Connect to external app"
2. SPA redirects to server-side and Spring Security redirects to authentication server
3. User authenticates and grants permission to my application
4. User is redirected back to server-side
5. Server-side gets JWT token and stores it in database
6. Server-side redirects user to SPA

How is the first approach secure? Is it safe to authenticate with SPA only and send the response (access token, refresh token) to server-side without additional security measures? This would simplify the process because it's SPA + REST API.

Comment: What did you mean by "redirects user to SPA"?

Comment: To exchange authorization code with access token, you need client ID and secret. They will be leaked if you store them in SPA.

Comment: @pcalkins, server-side app redirects user back to the single page application

Comment: @defalt, client ID is required but client secret not (instead, PKCE is generated), so is it a big security leak if client ID is known to SPA?

Comment: It's secure then.